# c# nest: converting Nest.KeyItem to Nest.KeyedBucket? What would be the syntax?

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

We have aggregation query that returns back "CityIdCount" and "CityNameCount" like:

```
.Aggregations(aa => aa.Terms("CityIdCount", h => h.Size(0).Field("cityId")).Terms("CityNameCount", h => h.Size(0).Field("cityName"))
```

Above is not the complete query but only aggregations part of it.

```
           BucketAggregate cityCount = (Nest.BucketAggregate)cities.Aggregations["CityIdCount"];
            BucketAggregate cityName = (Nest.BucketAggregate)cities.Aggregations["CityNameCount"];
            var cityList = cityCount.Items;
            var cityNameList = cityName.Items;

            using (var cityIdListEnumerator = cityList.GetEnumerator())
            using (var cityNameListEnumerator = cityNameList.GetEnumerator())
            {
                while (cityIdListEnumerator.MoveNext() && cityNameListEnumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    var currCityIdObject = cityIdListEnumerator.Current;
                    var currCityNameObject = cityNameListEnumerator.Current;

                    City city = new City()
                    {
                        //Following is original nest 1.7 version line
                        CityId = Convert.ToInt32(((Nest.KeyItem)(currCityIdObject)).Key),

                        //How can we convert it to nest 5.4? Below line gives error  
                        CityId = (Nest.KeyedBucket<int>)(currCityIdObject);

                        CityCount = Convert.ToInt32(((Nest.KeyItem)(currCityIdObject)).DocCount),
                        CityName = (((Nest.KeyItem)(currCityNameObject)).Key)
                    };
                    citiesList.Add(city);
                }
            }
```

Please check the comments in the above code. We need to convert Nest.KeyItem to Nest.KeyedBucket. Can anyone help how can we get cityId from Nest.KeyedBucket?

Comment: Would this do? ((Nest.KeyedBucket<int>)(currCityIdObject)).Key?

Comment: I would recommend using the `AggregationsHelper` exposed on the response as `.Aggs`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-aggregations.html#aggs-vs-aggregations